# Can't establish DB2 connection from container built from docker-compose.yml

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose, db2, containers

I am trying to use a [db2 docker image](https://hub.docker.com/r/ibmcom/db2) in a docker-compose-yml file, and when running `docker-compose up --build`, docker seems to build the two containers correctly. But when I try to connect to the database (through my local DBeaver instance), I'm getting this error:

[image]

[This answer](https://www.ibm.com/mysupport/s/question/0D50z000062l1CoCAI/db2-jdbc-gateway-gives-errorcode4499-sqlstate08004?language=en_US) states that *"It can occur when an alias is used for the gateway connection URL instead of the DB2 database name."*, but that's not my case (unless I'm missing some point...).

My docker-compose yml file:

```
       File: docker-compose.yml

   1   │ version: '3.8'
   2   │ 
   3   │ services:
   4   │   db2:
   5   │     image: ibmcom/db2
   6   │     container_name: db2_container
   7   │     ports:
   8   │       - "50000:50000"
   9   │     privileged: true
  10   │     environment:
  11   │       - LICENSE=accept
  12   │       - DB2INSTANCE=db2inst1
  13   │       - DB2INST1_PASSWORD=<password>
  14   │       - DBNAME=riskdb1
  15   │       - IS_OSXFS=true
  16   │     restart: always
  17   │     volumes:
  18   │       - <db_path>:/database
  19   │ 
  20   │   automation:
  21   │     build: automation
  22   │     container_name: automation_container
  23   │     ports:
  24   │       - "5001:5000"
  25   │     volumes:
  26   │       - <volume_path>:automation/data/output
  27   │     depends_on:
  28   │       - db2
```

My Os: macOS Monterey, v12.6

Comment: What hostname are you using for communication between your automation container and DB2?  If you are using localhost it probably won't work. Docker Compose set's up a network by default for the containers. The hostname will match the service name

Comment: I was using localhost indeed. Changed here to db2 (the service name). Now the error changed to ERRORCODE=-4499, SQLSTATE=08001.

Comment: So then the next step would be to tell Docker to allow communication between the two services on the network.  Try replacing `depends_on: -db2` to `links: -db2`

Comment: Still no success :(
Now the error is again ERRORCODE=-4499, SQLSTATE=08004.
Don't know if it is relevant, but the last log lines of my conteiner build status are:


PID     : 745
TID : 140393511068288 PROC : db2ts
INSTANCE: db2inst1             NODE : 000
HOSTNAME: 73b527d3e30b
FUNCTION: DB2 UDB, Text Search, CieServiceOnNode::getKeyValue, probe:550
DATA #1 : <preformatted>
ossError= 0, ossProcStatus.status= 257, ossProcStatus.exitcode= 127

Comment: If you shell into the db2 container, then become the Db2-instance-owner (e.g. db2inst1), dot in the db2profile (e.g. `. ~db2inst1/sqllib/db2profile`), does the command `db2 connect to riskdb1` complete successfully ?